# 2002 Nissan Quest breaking down

Tags: nissan, rough-idle, misfire, quest

I was given the vehicle after it had sat for over 7 months. It sat with 3/4-1/2 a tank of gas. It was not cranked once. It is now idling and running very rough. It doesn't want to accelerate and when you try to force it it starts feeling like it's being pushed from behind (almost rocked) and tries to bog down and die. It doesn't like to go over 30 mph and the service engine light is blinking. It is also blowing grey/blue smoke at pretty much all times from cranking to idling to accelerating and even when decelerating. It is also shaking badly during idle and when coming to a stop. I have had the fuel injector replaced as well as all 6 spark plugs and wires.